# Does Git Rebasing Alter the Commit Tree

Tags: git, rebase

I was seeing this very reliable tutorial which said rebasing would cause new commits with a different SHA keys ONLY because the parent to which it points to is now different and everything else is identical.

However if this is true and nothing else changes, then if we traverse the latest rebased commit by drilling down into its root-tree, its subtrees and blobs wouldn't it be identical to original rebased tree?

By definition shouldn't the latest rebased commit tree contain an union of content from both master and rebased branches? In which case the commit should point to a new root-tree structure having new subtrees, blobs and possibly new node additions, be it subtrees or more blobs.

Comment: Are you asking us to refute an unnamed tutorial that you are only paraphrasing, not quoting, from?

Comment: @chepner I am only trying to understand the git mechanics and nothing else

Answer (score 3):

Without something like a link to the tutorial itself, it's impossible to say whether it's wrong, or you're just [holding it wrong](http://mashable.com/2010/06/24/iphone-4-reception-response/). :-)  However, `rebase` works internally as if by doing a series of `git cherry-pick` operations.

In fact, interactive rebase literally runs `git cherry-pick`.  Non-interactive rebase uses `git format-patch` and `git am` instead, when it can.

Both rebases will, by default, attempt not to copy commits that do not need to be copied.  That is, if the *onto* target of some to-be-copied commit (as computed internally after applying previous commits and/or from the `--onto` argument if any) is the same parent the commit already has, the underlying rebase can simply fast-forward the in-progress new anonymous branch over that commit, rather than copying it.  In this case, the SHA1s all remain undisturbed.  You can explicitly disable this behavior with `-f`, `--force-rebase`, or `--no-ff`.  As long as the time stamp on the new copy differs, it will then acquire a different SHA1 hash (even if/though everything else is the same).

Internally, the *onto* target is simply `HEAD`, since rebase works internally by using detached HEAD mode.  As each old commit gets copied to the new one, Git simply needs to make a new commit as usual (or for that one special case, step HEAD forward using `git reset`).

In general, though, as long as *something* has changed—which is definitely true if the parent ID has changed (i.e., the *onto* target differs)—Git must construct a new commit.  It does by, in effect, applying the original commit as a patch atop the current commit.

Note that this *cannot* work for merge commits, which cannot be represented as a single patch.<sup>1</sup>  As a consequence, `git rebase` normally *strips out* merge commits entirely.  The interactive rebase script has code to "preserve" merges, but it really cannot *preserve* a merge (except for the special fast-forward case): instead, it must *re-perform* the merge, with all the consequences of doing so.

---

<sup>1</sup>A merge commit could be represented by at least two patches, one against the first parent and one against every other parent, but not by just one.  However, such a representation would be useless for our purposes: `--preserve-merges` is intended to transplant the merge into a new commit chain, with a different starting code-base, so we can expect the diff against the second (and any additional) parents to change.

Answer (score 1):

Git creates new SHA IDs for the commits, as well as for all of the metadata in the trees, like the blobs. You're correct that the content is identical, but all of the IDS have changed entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The point is the git is implemented like a linked list! therefore when you lost a link there is no way to track it back.

The easiest way to integrate the branches, is the merge command. It performs a three-way merge between the two latest branch snapshots creating a new snapshot (and commit).

[image]

However, in rebase you can take the patch of the change and reapply it on top of your master branch.

[image]

You can read more here:

> https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing

I hope it helps ;)

Comment: I was referring to the contents of the new commits created by rebasing. I just cannot see (from that tutorial at least) how it is contains info from both the branches.

Comment: Check out the answer, I update it with more details.